# Does Selenium RC support IE8?

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-8, selenium, selenium-rc

Can anyone confirm if Selenium RC server fully supports IE8?

Answer (score 6):

I have successfully been running tests in IE8 with Selenium RC and Selenium Grid. I'm not sure about 'full' support as I see occasional issues with all versions of Internet Explorer, but if you find any reproducible issues you can raise them in one (or all) of the following places:

- OpenQA Jira: http://jira.openqa.org/
- Selenium Developers Google Group: http://groups.google.co.uk/group/selenium-developers
- Selenium Google Code Issues: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list

Answer (score 2):

At Sauce labs we have been using Selenium + IE8 for a while now. You can even use our service to test on IE8 yourself.

(Google us, I'm not pasting links, don't want this to sound like spam)

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to run selenium server and IE8 as Admin and things works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

For those new to Selenium, it might bear a reminder that this entry was posted back during the days of "Selenium 1.x" and if you want to find newer info about "Selenium 2" which is based on WebDriver, then try these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium2 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriver tag URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I woking fine in IE8. I haven't had encountered any issues so far.